# how to avoid fieldset in drupal date field

Tags: 7, theming, datetime

I have a date field in registration form, I am using template for that. When I using  its outputs the html with fieldset. How can I remove that I wanna style likebleow fields.

Please see the image
[image]

**Its drupal 7**

Answer (score 7):

Use the latest full release or the [7.x-2.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/node/1075880) version of the [Date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date).

There is an new option `Render as a regular field` available there:

[image]

The option was added at the [Make it possible to disable fieldset for date field](https://www.drupal.org/node/1467712#comment-9323599) issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add this to your `template.php` file

```
function MYTHEME_date_combo($variables) {
  return theme('form_element', $variables);
}
```

Here '`MYTHEME`' should be you theme name defined in you `.info` file placed inside your theme directory.

Source: http://codekarate.com/blog/removing-fieldset-drupal-7-date-field

Answer (score 4):

It's easiest to do so with CSS.

```
#fieldset-wrapper-id {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
}
#fieldset-wrapper-id legend {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Since there is an API available to achieve this, I would highly recommend to follow that first.